# AutoPlay audio in asp.net webForm not working

Tags: asp.net, audio, html5-audio, autoplay

I want to autoplay audio on Timer Ticked events in asp.net webform but it's not working.
However, if I click the play button and play the audio once the audio plays automatically on the next ticked events. What could be the issue here?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"> 
         </asp:Timer>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is the code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string link = "Audio/" + "1.mp3";
    link = "<audio Controls autoplay ><Source src=" + link + " " + "type= audio/mpeg></Video>";
    Literal1.Text = link;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UpdatePanel` to  be able to work with [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.timer) as described in documentation:

> The Timer control enables you to perform postbacks at a specified
> interval. When you use the Timer control as a trigger for an
> UpdatePanel control, the UpdatePanel control is updated by using an
> asynchronous, partial-page update. You must include a ScriptManager
> object in a Web page to use the Timer control.
>
> You use the Timer control to update an UpdatePanel control by
> including the timer inside the UpdatePanel control. Alternatively, you
> can place the timer outside the UpdatePanel control and set the timer
> as a trigger.
>
> You can also initiate full postback of a complete Web page by
> including the Timer control in the Web page and not setting it as a
> trigger for an UpdatePanel control.

So, your code should look like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" /> 

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

See also: [How to use timer control in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032034/how-to-use-timer-control-in-asp-net)

Comment: doesnt work. I have googled it and found out that the problem is google chrome does not allow autoplay unless user interacts with the page like do a click event or so.

Comment: So was it working for other browsers then?